# "Editing help" page formatting appears broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

The formatting of the [editing help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help), linked from the sidebar when typing or editing a question or answer, appears quite broken:

[image]

Notice how the background horizontal lines are in inappropriate places, especially the one overlapping the line starting "spaces will be stripped off"; also the heading is not in the usual font for the site.

The [asking help](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page, linked from the same place, has no such formatting issues.

(I am using Firefox 3.6.16, though the page appears the same in IE8.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fix will be in the next deployment.