# Is the editing help page supposed to be this hideous?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

See [the editing help page.](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) In Safari 5, at the very least (the only browser I have available at the moment), it has no background at the top, unlike most of the English.SE site.

[image: usual background]

Take a look at the editing page (just in case this is a Safari problem, I'll put up a picture).

[image: editing page]

I know that this has been [asked before,](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/editing-help-page-formatting-appears-broken) but that was in May. The issue has either not been resolved at all, or was fixed, but somehow broke again. (Or was just never fixed for Safari, assuming of course that it was broken for Safari at the time of asking).

Comment: I see the same thing on Chrome (Windows) and IE9. Looks broken.

Comment: Same in Firefox 7

Comment: Same in Firefox 3.6.24 (Windows) and IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not supposed to be this hideous. There were some left-over styles still being applied from back in the days when that page was hideous-by-design (as in the question from May that you're referring to). Since that page's layout has been updated to match the rest of the site, that's no longer necessary. It'll look as expected after the next build of the site. Thanks!